# Why do most HANDLE related functions return 0 upon failure?

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, handle

Most functions that returns a handle, such as `OpenProcess`, `OpenFile`, `OpenThread`, `FindWindow`, etc, return 0 upon failure. I understand that return an invalid result to indicate failure is a good practice. However, if windows choose `-1` to be the `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, why don't these functions return `-1` upon failure?

Comment: I think that's what we call a *historical design choice*. Why the choice was made is unknown to everyone, except the person that made the choice. But once the choice was made, backwards compatibility dictates that it could not be changed.

Comment: So what is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` for? Why does MS still keep that macro?

Comment: @user3386109 Fully agree. One more point is the fact that in the first versions of MS OS's the handles where pointers to resources, and the null value can be compared to the `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Maybe this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040302-00/?p=40443 gives some more hints

Comment: Following the last link: *always read the manual*. Some functions return 0 on success, otherwise with an error code, and so on.

Comment: The manuals don't tell me why do functions return 0 instead of -1. They simply tell me what functions return. @WeatherVane

Comment: @KelvinZhang: Well it does, only look for `NULL`, not `0` in the text. The reason why some functions return `-1` is, as they say up front: historical...

Comment: It is the long shadow cast by Unix, plenty of code was ported to win16 through xenix.  Its open() function fails with -1 and 0 is a valid 'handle' for the stdout stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many conjectures you can make, but yes the reasons are historical and due to compatibility in the process of porting old 16bits code to newer one.
Some functions originally returned `-1` when failing, in the respect of C habit to return negative values on failure.
Moving to new 32bits versions, for the reason of compatibility mentioned above, lead to the creation of `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` equated to `-1`.
But because the handles sometimes were real pointers, and for the simplicity of comparison for `NULL` value many new functions were designed to return `NULL` on failure.
One interesting point is that `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` happens to be numerically equal to the pseudohandle returned by `GetCurrentProcess()`. So using an invalid handle in some functions could lead to valid results or terrible deadlocks as in the case of `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` used in a call to `WaitForSingleObject`. This will lead to an endless wait for the current process.
You can find the whole story, told from the authors, here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040302-00/?p=40443